# How do I determine the size of the stage in Snap?

Tags: size

How do I change or determine the size of the stage in Snap!?

Answer (score 4):

In the **Sensing** category, you can choose the [image] block.  Below is an example from some of my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can view and change the stage size from the Options menu (It looks like a sunburst symbol at the top of the IDE). There's an option called "Stage size..."

The default stage size is 480 by 360.

[image: Stage size menu option]

[image: Stage size dialog]